# Find Rank Using Druid via druid-datasketches extension

Tags: druid

Need to find rank of a company lets say McDonalds in various scenarios in druid. For this purpose I came across an extension called "druid-datasketches" which I think can be helpful.
After going through the documentation I was able to form this query but its incorrect.

```
{
"queryType": "topN",
"dataSource": "company",
"granularity": "all",
"intervals": [
    "2021-01-01T00:00:00/2021-02-28T23:59:59"
],
"dimension": "corporation",
"threshold": 50,
"metric": "rank",
"aggregations": [
    {
        "type": "doubleSum",
        "name": "cr_sales",
        "fieldName": "cr_sales"
    },
    {
        "type": "quantilesDoublesSketch",
        "name": "skechers",
        "fieldName": "cr_sales",
        "k": 4096
    }
],
"postAggregations": [
    {
        "type": "quantilesDoublesSketchToRank",
        "name": "rank",
        "field": {
            "type": "fieldAccess",
            "fieldName": "skechers"
        },
        "value": "McDonalds"
    }
],
"context": {
    "skipEmptyBuckets": true,
    "minTopNThreshold": 100000,
    "populateResultLevelCache": false
}
```

}

Need some guidance to be able to form the correct query.

Comment: Do you have any error messages from the log files?